# A (strictly) `Growable` mutable `Seq`

Tags: scala-collections

I need a (mutable) `Seq` that is *only* `Growable`. I do not need to update any index or shrink the collection or `transform` it (or any other form of mutation), Just grow it (`+=`) and I want to actively protect the collection from other mutations.

- The problem with `Buffer`s is that they are not just `Growable` but also `Shrinkable` and can be `transformed`.
- (mutable.)`Seq` is not `Shrinkable` but it can transform and it is *not* `Growable`

To my (cursory) understanding of scala collection, there is no concrete implementation that has the exact traits that I'm looking for so I believe I have to implement my own?

EDIT:

I tried 

`val hands : collection.Seq[Team] with Growable[Team] = mutable.Seq[Team]()`

in an attempt to make the nominal type conform to my requirements, actively preventing the client to call the undesired mutating methods on `hands` but it says types does not conform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
  val hands : collection.Seq[Team] with Growable[Team] = mutable.Buffer[Team]()
```